# Rotating labels around point features at a given distance

Tags: qgis, labeling

I've to rotate labels dynamically around point features at a given distance (e.g. 10 map units):

[image]

Is there an option in the layer properties to do this?

Comment: Should the position of the label on the circle be determined automatically? Or is it given?

Comment: I want to rotate the labels with the 'Rotate labels' or 'Rotate point symbols' tool.

Comment: It is possible to use to data-defined or fixed values to control offset from point and rotation. Unfortunately, I can't give you a specific answer as I don't know whether the rotation and offset distances are fixed for all values, based on an attribute, or vary to avoid other map features/labels. Will the output be viewed at different scales? Using an offset in map units could be problematic when scaling.

Comment: The output scale is fixed. Creating new fields for saving offset and rotation values is not an issue.

Comment: You have two option in a "placement" configuration "arround the point" and the "offset from point",and you can put labels arround the point with the angle taht you want.Checked in Qgis 2.18.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way you can do this is creating a field that has the rotation around the point that you want displayed (-180 to 180). In my example I randomly assigned values for the rotation desired around the point. After you have your desired rotation in a field then you need to calculate X Y offsets using the field calculator in the form of `X, Y`. You can calculate X by using the formula `Offset * Sin(Rotation)` and you can calculate Y by using `-Offset * Cos(Rotation)` The negative is because positive Y is down in QGIS.

Assuming you have a field that defines your desired rotation, here's how to set up the offsets field and the label settings to get what you are looking for.

**1. Create the Offsets field from your rotation value**

Open the attributes table for the point layer you are labeling and open the field calculator. Set the output field type to `Text, unlimited length (text)` and in the expression tab enter in the following expression

```
concat( 10 * sin("rotation"*pi()/180) , ',', -10 * cos("rotation"*pi()/180) )
```

In this example `rotation` is the name of the field that has the rotation about the point -180 to 180 with 0 being north, and 10 is the offset value. the `pi()/180` is for converting degrees to radians.

**2. Set up your labels**

Go to your `Layer Properties` and `Labels` tab. Set up your `Label with` expression however you want. In my example I'm labeling with the rotation values so you can see the end results based on rotation value.

Select the `Placement` option in the `Labels` tab and select `Offset from point`. On the line labeled `Offset X,Y` select the drop down button on the far right and expand `Field Type` and select the `Offsets` field that you generated from the rotation values.

Still on the `Placement` menu scroll down to `Data defined` and select the drop down button next to `Rotation` and select `edit...`. In the expression editor that pops up put in `-"rotation"` where rotation is the name of the field with the rotation values. The reason it is negative is because this rotation is opposite of rotation about the point. E.g. -45 degrees you position the text 45 degrees left of North, but the rotation described here of -45 degrees would rotate the text 45 degrees to the right instead of the left.

That should label all of your points similar to the diagram that you have drawn. An example of my output is shown below with rotation values labeled.

[image]